# Disabling Video Out of App Videos on iOS devices

Tags: iphone, ios, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller, ipad-2

I have an iOS app which I am developing, this app has videos which are copyright material. I am allowed to use them to be seen within the app but not to be seen when connected to a TV. ie. via HDMI or component - instead when a video is playing and someone connects a tv out lead to the device i need to display a screen like a splash screen saying it is not allowed etc...

So my question is how can i catch when a tv out device has been connected to the device? or how can i know when tv out has been requested to the MPMoviePlayerController (which is what im using to display the video)?

I have searched everywhere for this and can not find any answer!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Technical Q&A QA1738: How to Opt Out of Video Mirroring](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1738/_index.html). Here is what you basically need to do:

```
UIScreen *aScreen;

NSArray *screens = [UIScreen screens];
for (aScreen in screens) 
{
    if ([aScreen respondsToSelector:@selector(mirroredScreen)] 
              && [aScreen mirroredScreen] == [UIScreen mainScreen]) 
    {
        // The main screen is being mirrored.
    }
    else 
    {
        // The main screen is not being mirrored, or
        // you are not running on a compatible device.
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks im assuming i would need some kind of notification to fire off to first detect new screen then to run this code above?

Comment: Yes, if you look at the ExternalDisplay code linked in the article, you'll see that they register for UIScreenDidConnectNotification and UIScreenDidDisconnectNotification.